# Salesforce StackExchange Should No Longer Be In Beta

Tags: discussion, support

I think it is time to take this site out of beta and make it official already. As of this post, we have been in beta for 380 days. The [stats support us getting out of beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce).

[image: Stats]

What do you think? How can we finally become official?

---

So, it has been over half a year since this was posted. We have been in beta for the last 6 months. I am starting to feel like the we have kind of been put on the back burner. This has been a topic for a long time now, and with the solid community we have, it would be great to hear an update on what is going on and when we can expect to be officially recognized.

**EDIT:** April Kyle Nassi is reaching out for a followup. More details [here](https://twitter.com/jessealtman/status/429368491997544448)

---

The [StackExchange Twitter handle responded](https://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/430348247862083584):

> we’ve had a design backup, but have 200% more designers now. DON’T
>   GIVE UP ON US!

---

Another update:

StackExchange is working on it, but there are some challenges with Salesforce's IP. Makes sense but it is moving forward!

Check out @StackExchange's Tweet: https://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/474623395339206656

Comment: What happens when this site leaves Beta besides it not saying "Beta" anymore?

Comment: The only difference from our perspective is that they will give the site a custom look and feel. Other than that, it will be nice to be "official"!

Comment: I think some reputation based functionality will also require more reputation once we're no longer in beta. Though there appears no mention of this on the privileges page  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=all

Comment: Something new for this topic? It is april 2014 right now...

Comment: Are there some updates for this topic? I mean this was announced by several months, but until now nothing has happened :(

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They announced we'll be leaving beta soon in a recent podcast. See/listen http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/podcast-49-the-one-where-we-edited-out-the-title-reference/ for details.

Comment: Awesome! I guess I should check that stuff out more often. We definitely deserve it.

Comment: Good to hear!  I find the Stackexchange format far more useful than forums.

Comment: That `soon` was announced almost 3 months ago! Can't wait anymore!!! :)

Comment: @mast0r I 100% agree. This is taking way too long! https://twitter.com/jessealtman/status/429368491997544448

Comment: Almost one year later, we still appear to be no closer.

Answer (score 11):

I think this forum has deserved to go out of the beta right now and become a full member of the stack exchange community.

Comment: totally agree !

Comment: agree, agreeing, agreed!

Comment: I'm not sure what has taken so long, but I agree, it is definitely time for a full fledged site.